# EMR + DynamoDB workflow setup throws Hive.createTable NoSuchMethodError JsonErrorResponseHandler

Tags: workflow, hive, boto, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I am trying to set up EMR workflow (with DynamoDB and Hive) using boto Python API.
I could run the script manually using Amazon EMR Console. However with boto it fails 
at creating tables.

Here's the boto script that sets up the EMR workflow:

```
args1 = [u's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script',
         u'--base-path',
         u's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/',
         u'--install-hive',
         u'--hive-versions',
         u'0.7.1.3']
args2 = [u's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script',
         u'--base-path',
         u's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/',
         u'--hive-versions',
         u'0.7.1.3',
         u'--run-hive-script',
         u'--args',
         u'-f',
         u's3://foo/foobar/hiveexample.sql']
steps = []
for name, args in zip(('Setup Hive','Run Hive Script'),(args1,args2)):
    step = JarStep(name,
                   's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
                   step_args=args
                   )
    steps.append(step)

conn = boto.connect_emr()
job_id = conn.run_jobflow('EpisodePlay', u's3://foo/foobar/logs/',
                           steps=steps,
                           master_instance_type='m1.small',
                           slave_instance_type='m1.small',
                           num_instances=5,
                           hadoop_version="0.20.205",
                           ami_version="2.0")
```

However the script fails with the below exception.

```
Hive history file=/mnt/var/lib/hive_07_1/tmp/history/hive_job_log_hadoop_201203161922_1801322338.txt
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:663)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient$1.call(DynamoDBClient.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient$1.call(DynamoDBClient.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.runWithRetry(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.describeTable(DynamoDBClient.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe.verifyDynamoDBWriteThroughput(DynamoDBSerDe.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe.initialize(DynamoDBSerDe.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:900)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLineInternal(CliDriver.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
Command exiting with ret '255'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I was not using the correct AMI version.
When I launched the workflow from the console it picked up the latest AMI version which had the support for DynamoDB connectivity, but that was not the case when the same was launched by boto script.

Please refer to this link : 
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB_PreRequisites.html

```
job_id = conn.run_jobflow('EpisodePlay', u's3://dfhivescript/episodePlay/logs/',
steps=steps,
master_instance_type='m1.small',
slave_instance_type='m1.small',
num_instances=5,
hadoop_version="0.20.205",
**ami_version="2.0.4") # Correct AMI version**
```